# How to use "entry.sh" as ENTRYPOINT in a DOCKERFILE?

Tags: docker, entry-point, ash

I have built a docker image from the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM cdi_monitoring:monitoring

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/ash","-c","/entry.sh","/32ULC_subset"]
```

The *cdi_monitoring* is another image that I am extending and that is working properly. The path to my working directory is `/home/casper/Downloads/data/32ULC_subset`.

Now when I try to run the image built above I get the error `/32ULC_subset: line 1: /entry.sh: not found` .Here is how I am running the Dockerfile:

```
sudo docker run --name cdi_monitoring --rm -it -v /home/casper/Downloads/data/32ULC_subset/:/home/casper/Downloads/data/32ULC_subset/ cdi_monitoring:wrapper ./ChangeDetectionIL /home/casper/Downloads/data/32ULC_subset/ /home/casper/Downloads/data/32ULC_subset/Konfiguration_CD/IL_Liste.txt /home/casper/Downloads/data/32ULC_subset/Konfiguration_CD/
```

**How can i fix this issue?**

Comment: How do those files get into the root directory of the running container?  Are they things that are in the base image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems you have path issues.

What is the location of your file **entry.sh** ? Is it really located at root path (i.e : **/**) ?

If not, you have two solutions. For the example, suppose your file is located in `/home/casper/Downloads/data`, then :

- **Solution 1 :** You need to update your `ENTRYPOINT` and give the full path

```
FROM cdi_monitoring:monitoring

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/ash","-c","/home/casper/Downloads/data/entry.sh","/home/casper/Downloads/data/32ULC_subset"]
```

- **Solution 2 :** You need to set your `WORKDIR` before the `ENTRYPOINT`

```
FROM cdi_monitoring:monitoring

WORKDIR /home/casper/Downloads/data

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/ash","-c","./entry.sh","./32ULC_subset"]
```

Comment: Could also set the working directory in the `docker run --workdir ...` however the `Dockerfile` would still need to be updated using relative paths (relative to the working directory of course) rather than absolute from the `/` file system.

Comment: @masseyb yes, this is also a solution. But I'm not a big fan of this one as you'll be forced to modify your `docker run` command in order to make it work. In my opinion, a Dockerfile should be written in a way that your `docker run` command should not fail if ran without any parameter.

Comment: A solution nonetheless ;) In my opinion the `Dockerfile` should be as short and concise as possible and if the container requires runtime parameters then keep them in `docker-compose` or pass them on the command line in the `docker run`. Very opinionated.